# How to change background color after clicking the button

Tags: android, button

I have a set of buttons. Here I want, If I click one button then change its background color and then I click another button then change its color, and also change previous clicked button's color.
I used

```
setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.btnBg));
```

It changed the background color but It is not what I want. (I try this for Number pad)
[image]

Comment: "It changed the background color but It is not what I want" Specify exactly what you expected and what actually happened.

Answer (score 0):

1. Paste this code in onclick

   ```
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));

        }
    },   100);
   ```
2. it will change the color to white in 100 miiliseconds